# What happens to already running threads in IIS when a website recompiles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

I have an ASP.NET/C# 2.0 website running in IIS 7. A bug in one of the App_Code files caused the code to go into an infinite loop when trying to access a particular page.

When the offending code in App_Code is fixed, the website of course recompiles, preventing further requests from going into an infinite loop. But what happens to the threads that are stuck in the infinite loop and are still running when the code is changed? Are they automatically killed in order to recompile the site? If not, will they timeout at some point, or will they keep running until the website is stopped/restarted from IIS?

Comment: A question that rises is that, when it does, do you lose session state? But perhaps that is not relevant for you. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an activity triggers an application pool recycle, it will leave the old process alive long enough for any pending requests to complete, **within a timeout period**. If the pending requests haven't finished up in that time, it will forcibly terminate them.

Comment: +1. Note that when code is compiled/updated there is no triggering of appPool recycle - it is handled by ASP.Net runtime instead see [Application Restarts in App Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx). You can easily see that process does not go away by attaching debugger to one of w3wp and triggering code/web.config change. Looks like OP was interested in recycle (i.e. triggered by `iisreset` or explicit recycle action).